# How to add sequence number to group of rows based on status column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a group of rows in order. Column "Status" has only two value 0/1. Now, I'd like to add a sequence number / group number for each 0/1 set. there can be 1 to many rows of 0's but only one 1 for each set in the end. How do I add a new column as sequence number that only increases when there is a 1.

example:

```
ID  Status  Row Group Number
1   0   1
2   0   1
3   1   1
4   0   2
5   1   2
6   0   3
7   0   3
8   0   3
9   1   3
```

question is how do I get the third column?

thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmmm . . . This is a cumulative sum up to the previous row (plus 1).  So, in SQL Server 2012+, you can do:

```
select t.*,
       1 + sum(status) over (order by id) - status as rowgroupnumber
from t;
```

Comment: I think you need to `+ 1` on your `rowgroupnumber` value

Comment: @Nicarus . . . That's sort of funny.  I put that in the text and then didn't put it in the query.

Comment: very clever use of the status column. This works and I did have to +1 case when status = 0 to make the set line up. I kept thinking about complex join/rank function etc. without any success. Thank you!